# Is it necessary to have rows wrapped in a row class in Bootstrap?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am curious if I need to wrap each of the rows in a grid of results within a row class div. In my case the results are identical dimensions. So I would have:

```
<div class="col-md-4">
...
</div>
<div class="col-md-4">
...
</div>
<div class="col-md-4">
...
</div>
<div class="col-md-4">
...
</div>
<div class="col-md-4">
...
</div>
<div class="col-md-4">
...
</div>
<div class="col-md-4">
...
</div>
```

Is there any specific benefit to using row if I am creating a grid? So like this:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
    ...
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
    ...
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
    ...
    </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
    ...
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
    ...
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
    ...
    </div>
</div>
```

I understand for other types of layouts where content is uneven then the row is essential. But again assuming identical dimensions is the first method acceptable?

Comment: yes it is and wrap all in container

Answer (score 0):

According to my understanding:

`.row` gives you two imp styling:

```
margin-right: -15px;
margin-left: -15px;
```

Which nullifies the effect of container's styling:

```
padding-right: 15px;
padding-left: 15px;
```

Hence it is necessary to use `row` to make sure your `container` styling is overwritten. It also provides additional styling of setting the `width` in various media queries.

There is no hard and fast rule that you should include it. Although it is good practice to include it in order to avoid unexpected result and adding additional styling.

Answer (score 0):

It's not necessary but it's better practice.

What `.row` actually does is that it "nullifies" the `padding-left` from the first column and `padding-right` from the last column by having `margin: 0 -15px;`

Using `.row` allows you to create your page filling the entire `.container`. Otherwise you will waste 30px of the viewport's width which is problem when the viewport's total width is only 320px.

It is handy also when you create nested grids. If you don't wrap your columns inside a .row, you will end up having padding: 0 15px; in your nested "row". Nested columns should look like this unless you want to have 15px of padding on both sides:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-4></div>
        <div class="col-md-8></div>
      </div>
    </div>
    ...
  </div>
</div>
```